# Passing variables between Express Router and controller logic

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to modularize my code and utilize function calls from express router to an external module containing my controller logic. How does one pass back to the router the variables after processing the request?

```js
const express = require('express') ;
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser') 

const requestSomething = require('./controller/abc.js'); 
  


router.post('/', function (req,res, next){
    requestSomething() <----// Need Variable from this
    next()
  },function(req,res,next){
      sendOrder(X) <--------//So I can use it further along in chain
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

```js
//Controller logic, how to send body back to router??

const requestSomething = (req,res,next)=>{
  let options = { .... };
    requestSomething(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      let x = JSON.parse(body); <--- How do I pass this back to router?
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have to use promise for async behavior.
there are couple of libraries out there like [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) JavaScript Promise's ,[Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)

you can use any of this.

lets say on your server.js file you have to write something like this

```
router.post('/', function (req,res, next){
  requestSomething().then((x)=>{
    return x;
  }).then((x)=>{
    sendOrder(X) 
  }) <----// Need Variable from this

});
```

on Middleware part (lets say your controller )

```
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  let options = { };
 requestSomething(options, function (error, response, body) { //API Call
  if (error) {
     return reject(error);
  }
   let x = JSON.parse(body); //<--- How do I pass this back to router?
   return resolve(x);
 })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I have been trying to get it to work, but I am getting an error. Cannot read property 'then' of undefined, on requestSomething().then. The function call does occur though.

Comment: requestSomething() Is it API call ?

Comment: Yes it is an API call.

Answer (score 0):

In your case its an async function, you will have to use promise for that. Promise is an object can be returned by an sync or async function, which contains the success and failure result of the function depending upon the condition. check [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/02/16/how-javascript-promises-work/) for more info.

Like in your router:

```
 router.post('/', function (req,res, next){
        requestSomething().then(function(x){
         next();
     }).catch(function(onError){
     }); //but the problem is, it will not wait for next. so you can use in then part 
//        next()
      },function(req,res,next){
          sendOrder(X) <--------//So I can use it further along in chain
      }
    );
```

If I understood your requirement. 
Please read more about promise calls in javascript.